# WebLogic WLST find AuthenticationProviderName

Tags: ldap, weblogic, wlst

I'm looking for the solution which provides me to find Authentication Provider name and place it to variable. I want something like that:

```
LDAPProviderName = getAuthenticationProviderName(ProviderClassName='weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAuthenticationProviderImpl')
cd('/base_domain/serverConfig/SecurityConfiguration/base_domain/Realms/myrealm/AuthenticationProviders/' + LDAPProviderName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found a dirty workaround for that:

```
import re
AuthProviders = find('ProviderClassName')
LDAPProviderRegex = re.compile(r'LDAPAuthenticationProviderImpl')
LDAPProvider = filter(LDAPProviderRegex.search, AuthProviders)
LDAPProviderStr = str(LDAPProvider)
LDAPProviderSub = re.sub(r"\sProviderClassName.*$", "", LDAPProviderStr)
LDAPProviderName = re.sub(r"^[[]['][/].*[/](.*)$", "\\1", LDAPProviderSub)
```